# react is not recognized as an internal or external command or operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to create a react project but I got an error like this;

'create-react-app' is not recognized as an internal or external command or operable program or batch file

Comment: Sounds like you skipped the step where you install create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

This can solved

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

if the error still there you should install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/)